# Code formatting in Aptana 3

Tags: html, formatting, aptana

I'd like to know how can I find **HTML** code formatting in Aptana Studio 3.0 which had shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F in Aptana 2.x?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aptana Studio 3 should have formatting for a number of languages now.  The shortcut for formatting should be the same as in Studio 2: Ctrl+Shift+F.  You should be able to see a list of languages where formatting is supported under Preferences > Aptana > Formatter.

Answer (score 7):

Under the menu 'Source'>'Format' Shortcut is Shift+Cmd+F
[image: Under the menu 'Source'>'Format' Shortcut is Shift+Cmd+F]

Or

Right-click the source-code and select 'Source'>'Format' Shortcut is Shift+Cmd+F
[image: Right-click the source-code and select 'Source'>'Format' Shortcut is Shift+Cmd+F]

Answer (score 3):

In Aptana Studio 3 this feature it's still not available. They replied me in their forums:
"It will make a reappearance at some point. We do have HTML Tidy today".

Answer (score 1):

To update this somewhat for those who may end up here. In Aptana V3.0.9 there is formatting support (via Window -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Formatter) for HTML as the question asks (and also CSS, JavaScript, JSON, PHP, Ruby/ERB, XML).

This can be applied as before with Ctrl-Shift-F

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps formatting is not binded to that shortcut anymore? see [modifying shortcuts](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Modifying_your_shortcut_keys)

Comment: Sorry, I was not so precise with question... I need HTML code formatting which I don't find.